# Regex for 0.0 to 1

Tags: c#, regex

I think the title is descriptive

valid: `0.1, 0.15, 0.25, .... and 1`

How to include the `1` is the main challenge here. Thanks.

**Update**

Sorry I can't write the code. It's a legacy application that I don't have access to the source code. The application validation method are already embedded and am using the RegularExpression validator embedded in the app

Comment: Why not just try to parse as a number ? Regex is not the solution for everything.

Comment: I'm wondering why all correct regex solutions are voted down (Lolo, Bryan Oakley and Andre Calil's oney). +1 for them.

Comment: @H2CO3 Indeed, thank you for the support. SO would be a better place if all downvote should be justified

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regular expressions let you choose between patterns (ie: match pattern A OR pattern B). You do this with the | character (eg: A|B).

Try this:

```
^(0(\.[0-9]+)?|1(\.0+)?)$
```

Comment: Man, do you believe that `1.1` should be valid? Reading the question I don't think so... (side note: I hadn't downvoted you)

Comment: this works. Tested for 0.5, 0.55,1, 1.1[this correctly did not matched]. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will help:

```
^(?:(?:0)(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:1)(?:\.0+)?$
```

Comment: I prefer this answer over the current accepted one because it uses non-capturing groups (`?:`)

Answer (score 4):

This is not a Regex solution, because I don't think a Regex is a good solution for this. I would do it something like this:

```
string n = "0.1";
decimal number;
bool isNumber = Decimal.TryParse(n, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number);
return isNumber && number >= 0 && number <= 1;
```

Comment: While what you say is true, you're assuming the person asking the question has a choice. What if they are configuring a tool and their only option is to specify patters (for example, imagine a syntax coloring library which lets you match colors to patterns).

Comment: @BryanOakley, you are absolutely right, this might not be an option for the OP. The OP is always free to use my answer or disregard it - not mentioning the option of not using Regex in the answers to such a question would be wrong. When I posted my answer, there were already posted a few Regex based solutions, so I assumed the OP didn't need anymore of those.